# JQuery не добавляется класс при нажатии

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько svg сердечек

```
<svg id="svg_2" width="640" height="480" viewbox="0 0 640 480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path d="m219.28949,21.827393c-66.240005,0 -119.999954,53.76001 -119.999954,120c0,134.755524 135.933151,170.08728 228.562454,303.308044c87.574219,-132.403381 228.5625,-172.854584 228.5625,-303.308044c0,-66.23999 -53.759888,-120 -120,-120c-48.047913,0 -89.401611,28.370422 -108.5625,69.1875c-19.160797,-40.817078 -60.514496,-69.1875 -108.5625,-69.1875z"/>
</svg>
```

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии сердечко меняло цвет.
Реализовал таким образом:

```
$('#svg_2').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('filled');
});
```

CSS-код

```
svg{
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

#svg_2{
  fill:transparent; 
  stroke:#f00;
  stroke-width:6px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:fill .3s;
}
#svg_2.filled{
  fill:#f00;
}
```

Работает, но только на первый объект, игнорируя последующие.
Как это можно исправить?
https://jsfiddle.net/pq65rbdj/2/

Answer (score 1):

Это связанно с тем, что вы используете id и отталкиваетесь от него. id может быть только ОДИН уникальный на всю страницу. Поэтому скрипт обращается к первому, и после этого перестает выполняться. В Вашем случаи на странице несколько раз есть элемент с id="svg_2".

Стоит сделать вот так вот:

```
$('.js-heart').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('filled');
});
```

Обращайтесь к классу svg элемента. При этом, естественно, добавьте ему класс.

```
<svg id="svg_2" class="svg-heart js-heart" width="640" height="480" viewbox="0 0 640 480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path d="m219.28949,21.827393c-66.240005,0 -119.999954,53.76001 -119.999954,120c0,134.755524 135.933151,170.08728 228.562454,303.308044c87.574219,-132.403381 228.5625,-172.854584 228.5625,-303.308044c0,-66.23999 -53.759888,-120 -120,-120c-48.047913,0 -89.401611,28.370422 -108.5625,69.1875c-19.160797,-40.817078 -60.514496,-69.1875 -108.5625,-69.1875z"/>
</svg>
```

Стили:

```
.svg-heart {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  fill:transparent; 
  stroke:#f00;
  stroke-width:6px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:fill .3s;
}

.svg-heart.filled{
  fill:#f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте классы, а не идентификаторы:

```js
$('.heart').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('filled');
});
```

```css
svg{
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

.heart{
  fill:transparent; 
  stroke:#f00;
  stroke-width:6px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:fill .3s;
}
.heart.filled{
  fill:#f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="640" height="480" viewbox="0 0 640 480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path id="svg_2" class="heart" d="m219.28949,21.827393c-66.240005,0 -119.999954,53.76001 -119.999954,120c0,134.755524 135.933151,170.08728 228.562454,303.308044c87.574219,-132.403381 228.5625,-172.854584 228.5625,-303.308044c0,-66.23999 -53.759888,-120 -120,-120c-48.047913,0 -89.401611,28.370422 -108.5625,69.1875c-19.160797,-40.817078 -60.514496,-69.1875 -108.5625,-69.1875z"/>
</svg>

<svg width="640" height="480" viewbox="0 0 640 480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path id="svg_2"  class="heart" d="m219.28949,21.827393c-66.240005,0 -119.999954,53.76001 -119.999954,120c0,134.755524 135.933151,170.08728 228.562454,303.308044c87.574219,-132.403381 228.5625,-172.854584 228.5625,-303.308044c0,-66.23999 -53.759888,-120 -120,-120c-48.047913,0 -89.401611,28.370422 -108.5625,69.1875c-19.160797,-40.817078 -60.514496,-69.1875 -108.5625,-69.1875z"/>
</svg>

<svg width="640" height="480" viewbox="0 0 640 480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path id="svg_2"  class="heart" d="m219.28949,21.827393c-66.240005,0 -119.999954,53.76001 -119.999954,120c0,134.755524 135.933151,170.08728 228.562454,303.308044c87.574219,-132.403381 228.5625,-172.854584 228.5625,-303.308044c0,-66.23999 -53.759888,-120 -120,-120c-48.047913,0 -89.401611,28.370422 -108.5625,69.1875c-19.160797,-40.817078 -60.514496,-69.1875 -108.5625,-69.1875z"/>
</svg>
```